# Getting warning Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableData' from NSData

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, nsdata

I am getting warning::Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableData' from 'NSData' in below code

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length [webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    if( xmlParser )
    {
        xmlParser = nil;
        [xmlParser release];
    }

    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:theXML];
    webData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];//WARNING

    xmlParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData] autorelease];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [connection release];
}
```

Comment: You should accept some answers from your previous questions.

Comment: Check out the SO FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
webData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an NSData to an NSMutableData. NSMutableData contains logic which enables it to mutate, and this logic would be gone if you point it to an NSData object. What you should do instead is append the data, using the following syntax:

```
[webData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
```